# Quarkus OpenTelemetry across multiple services

Tags: java, microservices, quarkus, open-telemetry, propagation

I am trying to create open telemetry for my quarkus microservices with info from below:

https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry

I have changed the application.properties with propagator setting, build.gradle as well as added the @WithSpan in the code. However, this is creating a new span for every method with the WithSpan annotation. How can I have the trace/span carried forward for each of the called methods so we can see the time taken for each of them? Also do i need to do anything else in the code for enabling tracing across multiple Quarkus services? I do see the trace separately for each of the services but it's not showing me the trace of flows from one service to the other. the tracingcontext is null

Thank you in advance

Best Regards
SG

Comment: Just realized. We are on Quarkus 2.6.x whereas the examples point to Quarkus 3.1.1 in which the cross-service tracing works without any changes to the code. Any idea how this can be achieved with 2.6.x?

Comment: There were multiple propagation improvements on Quarkus 2.13.x.
I recommend you to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i did upgrade to 2.13.x and tried. What's surprising is Quarkus demo application on the link https://quarkus.io/version/2.13/guides/opentelemetry works without any additional setup. I copied and created a 2nd service of the sample and then in the REST call explicitly called the other service. When i checked jaeger, i do see the service-to-service info. When i try the same thing with our application, it doesn't work. I am tempted to write the open telemetry logic in the code but wondering how the demo application is working without any of this setup. Any idea?

Comment: The OTel instrumentation is bundled inside Quarkus.
If you come up with a reproducer project, I can help debug it.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, Unfortunately the demo projects all work in isolation but when i try to import the same in my project, it doesn't work. i just confirmed the trace id is not sent so the parent trace is blank in the 2nd service when it doesn't worl

Comment: How are you performing the calls between services? REST? Which client?

Comment: REST. I was using UriBuilder before but switched to RestClientBuilder which seems to have worked. Thanks